# S. Agnihotri, "Quantum cohomology and the Verlinde algebra"

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory, reference-request

I am looking for the Oxford PhD thesis of S. Agnihotri, "Quantum cohomology and the Verlinde algebra". I can't seem to find it online. Does anyone know how / where I can find this? Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried using interlibrary loan (or tracking down Agnihotri)?

Comment: In arXiv:0909.2347 by Korff and Stroppel, they refer to this thesis at the top of page 3: "A mathematical proof [that a certain fusion ring is isomorphic to a quatum cohomology ring specialized at q=1] seems to be contained in the unpublished, unfortunately not anymore available, work [1]."  Not that this is helpful, except perhaps in suggesting that you are not the only person who has been unable to find it. 


Answer (score 4):

It's unlikely that you can find the thesis itself without going through a well-connected library system (and perhaps not even then).    Most dissertations don't get published in full but may be reflected in related publications.   In this case it's problematic since there is only one paper listed for Sharad Agnihotri on MathSciNet; the co-author Chris Woodward (at Rutgers) is presumably easier to contact directly.   Note that this 1998 paper does refer to the 1995 Oxford thesis in question.   MathSciNet currently lists 33 articles and 9 reviews referring to the joint paper:

MR1671192 (2000a:14066) 14N35 (14H60 14N15), Agnihotri, S. (NL-AMSTM); Woodward, C. [Woodward, Christopher T.] (1-RTG-HC),  Eigenvalues of products of unitary matrices and quantum Schubert calculus.  Math. Res. Lett. 5 (1998), no. 6, 817–836.

By the way, MathSciNet now tries to include links to Math Genealogy, but there is none in this case; so it's not clear to me who the thesis advisor was.

Comment: His thesis advisor is Peter Braam. It is funny that both the advisor and the student quit mathematics quite a long time ago.